# Laravel change language with subdomain

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project and I have to make change language system but it should be with subdomains.

For example :

http://en.site.com/portal

http://de.site.com/portal

I use this command to get language text like "trans("home.title")" also I have a middleware to change language like :

```
    if($lang = Session::get('lang')){
      Lang::setLocale($lang);
    }
   return $next($request);
```

And I want to routing for decide to language from subdomain names. How can I do that? I just can do like that

```
Route:get("/lang/{lang}","LanguageController@change");
```

How it should be for subdomains ?

Thank you if you help me .

Comment: Instead of sub domains, have you thought about using the uri stem for routing? Such as `site.com/en/portal` and `site.com/de/portal`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII actually my point is SEO , I think subdomains better than subfolders for SEO.

Comment: I had the exact same problem so I decided to create my own package for it. For people having the same problem, have a look https://github.com/pmochine/Laravel-Tongue

Answer (score 3):

You only need 1 Middleware and that's all. It's pretty simple to achieve this in Laravel.

```
<?php
namespace AppHttpMiddleware;

use Closure;
use IlluminateSupportFacadesApp;

class LangMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $url_array = explode('.', parse_url($request->url(), PHP_URL_HOST));
        $subdomain = $url_array[0];

        $languages = ['en', 'de'];

        if (in_array($subdomain, $languages)) {
            App::setLocale($subdomain);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And then add the middleware to Kernel.php

Make sure that you have folders for subdomains that you need in resource/lang

I've found solution here: https://kovah.me/en/laravel-5-localization-based-on-the-subdomain/